# NGINX Not showing my index.html - Stays default

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/apexnetwork.org/public_html/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name   *.apexnetwork.org;
    server_name   .apexnetwork.org;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    } 
}
```

Heres my index:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <!-- Metadata, Stylesheet, Title -->
   <head>
      <title>Home | Apex Network</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="Apex Network">
      <meta name="author" content="Jerred Shepherd">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <!-- Navbar Start -->
   <body>
      <div class="navbar-wrapper">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
               <div class="container">
                  <div class="navbar-header">
                     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     </button>
                     <a class="navbar-brand accent" href="">Apex Network</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="play.php"><i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i> Play</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="forum"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Forum</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="shop.html"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Shop</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="stats"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Stats</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#">Login</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#">Register</a>
                              </li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <a href="play.php" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right hidden-sm hidden-xs">IP:
                        ApexNetwork.org</a>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Main Image -->
      <div class="bg-container">
         <img alt="Background Image" class="random bgimg" height="1920" width="640">
      </div>
      <div class="up2 text-center">
         <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h1 class="caption">Apex Network</h1>
            <p class="captionbody">Welcome to the ApexNetwork. Prison and factions</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="/play.html" role="button">Play Now &#187;</a>
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <!-- "Marketing" Area -->
      <div class="container marketing up">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
               <img class="img-circle glow" src="img/marketing/1.jpg" height="150" width="150" alt="Marketing Image 1">
               <h2>Voting!</h2>
               <p>Click here to go to the voting list!</p>
               <p> <a href="/vote.html">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button"></i>Vote &raquo;</button>
                  </a>
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
               <img class="img-circle glow" src="img/marketing/1.jpg" height="150" width="150" alt="Marketing Image 2">
               <h2>Donate!</h2>
               <p>Click here to go to the Buycraft webstore!!</p>
               <p> <a href="http://apexnetwork.buycraft.net/">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button"></i>Buy &raquo;</button>
                  </a>
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
               <img class="img-circle glow" src="img/marketing/3.jpg" height="150" width="150" alt="Marketing Image 3">
               <h2>Bans.</h2>
               <p>This is where you go, to see your ban reason.
               </p>
               <p> <a href="/bans">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button"></i>Details &raquo;</button>
                  </a>
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Footer -->
      <div id="footer">
         <div class="container hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <hr>
            <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
               <li class='pull-left'><a href="http://shepherdjerred.com/">Design by Jerred Shepherd
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li class="pull-right">
                  <a href="terms.html">Terms</a>
               </li>
               <li class="pull-right">
                  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
               </li>
               <li class="pull-right">
                  <a href="bans">Bans</a>
               </li>
               <li class="pull-right">
                  <a href="staff.html">Staff</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
            <br>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script>
         function getRandomInt(min, max) {
             return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
         }

         var imagePath = "img/bg/";

         function displayLogo() {
             var filename = "bg" + getRandomInt(1, 4).toString() + ".jpg";

             $(".random").attr({
                 "src": imagePath + filename,
             });
         }

         $(document).ready(function () {
             displayLogo();
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is my config for sites available. Yet every time i go onto my website, it says the default nginx index.

Comment: I see a website that appears to correspond with your index.html - are you still not seeing that? If so, try an incognito browser, or a different browser altogether. If you are seeing the website, let us know what you changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for server_name instead:

```
server_name   *.apexnetwork.org apexnetwork.org;
```

Comment: Didnt work at all :/

Comment: Well the. You're going to need to do some digging on your own. Examine logs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is my setup. I don't think your location config is correct.

```
location = / { index index.html =404; }
    location / {
        try_files $uri.html $uri/index.html $uri =404;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getting the default NGINX page, because your server_name tells NGINX that your configuration directory is not for `localhost`, therefore, NGINX uses the default installation directory to serve the `localhost` pages.

Test the following:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/apexnetwork.org/public_html/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name   *.apexnetwork.org localhost;
    #Alternate for default server would be to leave server_name out altogether to make the configuration a catch-all configuration

    #server_name   .apexnetwork.org;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    } 
}
```

The content of your page is actually irrelevant.  My advice is to start basic.  Avoid using the  more complex commands like `try_files` until you have the system working.

In that vein, while the `root` command does correctly operate in the server domain, all the documentation generally provides examples of `root` in the `location` domain.

The fact that you are seeing the NGINX page tells me that the issue is not with your accessing the server from the browser.  However, I notice that you have a comment indicating a need for `http://localhost` access, but your config file does not allow for this yet.  I imagine that you are trying to connect using `http://localhost`, and NGINX is looking at your config file saying to itself: "This configuration applies only to *.apexnetwork.org and not to localhost."

At http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html in the section titled "Serving Static Content", they discuss setting up localhost.  You will note in the examples that when server name is not provided that the configuration acts as a catchall and will serve `localhost` requests as well, so unless you are running a virtual server which serves many domains which are maintained in separate directory locations, you should follow the examples in the Begginer's Guide and leave out the server_name command.  This turns your configuration file into a catch-all which responds to all requests on port 80 regardless the domain requested in the URL.

If however, you are trying to serve *.apexnetwork.org as well as one or more other domains, and you wish apexnetwork.org to be the localhost, then you must use the server_name command, and the command would be the following:

```
server {
     listen 80 default_server;
     server_name *.apexnetwork.org localhost;
     #continue here with remainder of settings
}
```

This tells NGINX, that for everything within the `server` block belongs to all URLs at the domain *.apexnetwork.org (www.apexnetwork.org, mail.apexnetwork.org, vpn.apexnetwork.org, etc.) as well as all domains that match the word 'localhost' exactly.

Refer to this link for more details on use of server_name: [Server_Name Documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name)